# Initialise Keras StringLookup with DataFrame list column

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I have data in a `pd.DataFrame` column that has the following format:

```
   col
0  ['str1', 'str2', 'str3']
1  []
2  ['str1']
3  ['str20']
```

I using the following code to construct a lookup layer:

```
lookup_layer = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(max_tokens=335)
lookup_layer.adapt(df.col)
```

Which fails with:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

I also tried to concat the column into a single list, since the error suggested that the nested lists were the issue:

```
lookup_layer.adapt(itertools.chain(*df.col))
```

which resulted in:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I also tried various `tf.cast`/`tf.convert_to_tensor` calls, to no avail.

How can I convert my `DataFrame` string list column into something Tensorflow accepts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, you can use *[tf.ragged.constant](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ragged/constant)* over your `col` pd.Series.

```py
lookup_layer = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(max_tokens=335)
lookup_layer.adapt(tf.ragged.constant(df.col))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your list of string lists into a single list and then your `StringLookup` layer should work:

```py
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

d = {'col': [['str1', 'str2', 'str3'], [], ['str1', 'str2', 'str3'], ['str1', 'str2', 'str3']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

lookup_layer = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(max_tokens=335)
flattened_data = sum(list(df.col), [])
lookup_layer.adapt(flattened_data)
print(lookup_layer.get_vocabulary())
```

```
['[UNK]', 'str3', 'str2', 'str1']
```

Also check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists) on the performance of different list flattening methods.